# Prevent Gmail signatures from syncing between iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, gmail

I am trying to setup my email signature for my Gmail app on both my iPhone and iPad. However, whatever I setup on on my iPhone defaults on my iPad and vice versa.  Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Create one online and do not check the 'mobile signature' on your iPad and iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Gmail only differentiates between desktop and mobile signatures:

> You can create a mobile signature that will only be used when you send emails from the Gmail app. ([Link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/184194?hl=en))

Obviously, *mobile signature* applies to any mobile device with a compatible Gmail app.

Answer (score 0):

Your signature is synced between your devices and there is currently no way around this other than not using a signature and adding it yourself to each email.